# html css basic how can use css file in html file

Tags: html, css

how can I import CSS file into html file? html CSS basic how can use CSS file in html file
i have html file named 1.html and a CSS file named style.css that is placed in CSS folder and how can use CSS file?

Answer (score 2):

you just add in the head of your html document

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

if the file style.css is in css folder in the same folder as index.html